# Add entries from the top in to-do list angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have made this to-do list in angular but would like the posts entered to entered fro m the top instead the bottom.

my code:

HTML

```
                  <a href="{{url.title}}" class="link">
                      <p class="title">{{url.name}}</p>
                      <p class="url">{{url.title}}</p>
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 delete m-b-2">
                    <!--a href="javascript:" ng-click="edit($index)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a-->
                    <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="del($index)">Delete</a>

              </div>
        </div>
        </li>
```

JS

```
var urlFire = angular.module("UrlFire", ["firebase"]);
function MainController($scope, $firebase) {
  $scope.favUrls = $firebase(new Firebase('https://lllapp.firebaseio.com/'));
  $scope.urls = [];
  $scope.favUrls.$on('value', function() {
  $scope.urls = [];
  var mvs = $scope.favUrls.$getIndex();
    for (var i = 0; i < mvs.length; i++) {
      $scope.urls.push({
        name: $scope.favUrls[mvs[i]].name,
        title: $scope.favUrls[mvs[i]].title,
        key: mvs[i]
      });
    };
});
```

Comment: best not to use `$index` for functions like `delete()`. If you add any filters to `ng-repeat` it won't be position of object in original array rather it will be index in filtered array. Pass in whole object and do indexing in controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can use unshift() instead of push() when you add elements to your array. It adds the element at the beginning of your array instead of at the end, and since your angular view is based on the model it will add it on top.

Answer (score 0):

Use $scope.urls.splice(index_to_insert,0, object); so in your case you could do

```
var obj = {
        name: $scope.favUrls[mvs[i]].name,
        title: $scope.favUrls[mvs[i]].title,
        key: mvs[i]
      };
$scope.urls.splice(0,0, obj);
```